# What's the difference between the "Long Live the Queen" and "Royalist Ally" trophies?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-siege-3

I just completed the quest in Glitterdelve Mine quests and simultaneously got two trophies, but they seem to mean the exact thing:

> **Long Live the Queen** - You broke the siege at Glitterdelve and saved Queen Roslyn.
>
> **Royalist Ally** - You have shown unwavering support to the Crown.

It seems odd to have two trophies for the same thing. Are there differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Long Live the Queen* is unmissable and is awarded for completing the quest, but *Royalist Ally* is awarded for choosing the correct dialogue options when completing it:

> Choose dialogue options favorable to the Crown, and when asked, tell the Queen you'll try to spare Jeyne's life.

Comment: well it seems that achievements where broken before some patch. That don't know if you are in this case, but we May have to do it again.